# Installing Zend Framework with XAMPP

Tags: zend-framework, xampp

I've Xampp installed on my computer, and I want to install Zend Framework. I noticed there is already a folder called Zend inside the `xampp/php/PEAR/Zend`
Does it mean the Zend framework is already installed? On `phpinfo`, the `include_path` is `.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR`. Do I need to configure the path? What should be the new path?
Finally how can I know if the Zend framework is installed successfully and ready to use.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Zend framework is intensively developed and i doubt that xampp package include up to date version, so I recommend you to download latest full version from http://framework.zend.com/download/latest and extract the archive somewhere else.

Zend Framework requires no special installation steps. Simply download the framework,
extract it to the folder you would like to keep it in, and add the library directory
to your PHP include_path. To use components in the extras library, add the extras/library
directory to your PHP include_path, as well.
If you would like to use Zend_Tool, simply add bin/zf.bat (for Windows) or
bin/zf.sh (for anything else) to your system executable path.

The important files of Zend framework are located in ZendFramework-1.x.x\library\Zend in the archive and the ZendX (extras) are in ZendFramework-1.x.x\extras\ZendX. You might also need the ZendFramework-1.x.x\bin folder where is the ZendFramework console tool (zf)

I prefer extracting the "ZendFramework-1.x.x\library\Zend" into a folder lib\Zend and add it to the include path in php.ini

Answer (score -1):

#### Installing zend framework on Windows

1. Download zend framework.
2. Include the zend lib path on your php.ini file (If you have zend lib within `c:wampp/www/zend/library/` then put the path in `php.ini` include_path="c:/wampp/www/zend/library").
3. In the downloaded folder there is bin folder and there is file `zf.bat` so open that file and put the pull path of `php.exe`.
4. Go to command prompt and go to directory where you need your project.
5. Run this command:

   ```
   C:\\wampp\www\zend\bin\zf.bat create project project_name
   ```

Comment: The question was how to install ZF with XAMPP, so you're not really answering the question..